# How to switch loading bar condition based on views in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, loader, preloader

I am using https://github.com/chieffancypants/angular-loading-bar to run loader in angular view loader.

**What version of angular-loading-bar are you using?** 
angular-loading-bar v0.9.0
 
 
**What version of angular are you using?** 
I am using AngularJS v1.5.8
 
 
**What is the issue ?** 
Right now, I have added cfpLoadingBar in my app.config > route configuration ( its one time initialization,  
it is coming to all the page prior loading.
It is OK to set globally.
 
 
but, I want the spinner loading bar to all the page except two other views.
I have 4 views used in application.

- Home page view
- Detail page view
- Contact page view
- About Us page view
- I want spinner loading to **contactus** & **aboutus** page. 
  means "`cfpLoadingBarProvider.includeSpinner = true;`"
- and for Home page and details page I want to set template to show the welcome message HTML.
  means " `cfpLoadingBarProvider.spinnerTemplate = "<p>Welcome to my site</p>"` "

How can I handle single angular loading bar with different condition
can you help me on this.
is there any possibility?

What did you expect to happen?

1. Home page view - it should come with "welcome message"
2. Detail page view - it should come with "welcome message"
3. Contact page view - it should come with spinner as usual
4. About Us page view - it should come with spinner as usual

If not possible, then show me different way how to add condition to full fill my requirement..